# Getting ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended exception in LinqPad

Tags: oracle, linqpad

I'm doing this simple query:

```
from t in CmnTerms
from l in EsiTermsLocationV
where t.Attribute01 == l.TermName
select new { t.TermID, l.ZoneID }
```

and getting this error:

```
ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

   at Devart.Data.Oracle.bo.d()
   at Devart.Data.Oracle.bz.f()
   at Devart.Data.Oracle.bz.c()
   at Devart.Data.Oracle.i.a(Int32 A_0, bw A_1)
   at Devart.Data.Oracle.OracleCommand.InternalExecute(CommandBehavior behavior, IDisposable disposable, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, Boolean nonQuery)
   at Devart.Common.DbCommandBase.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior, Boolean nonQuery)
   at Devart.Common.DbCommandBase.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader()
   at IQToolkit.Data.DbEntityProvider.Executor.ExecuteReader(DbCommand command)
   at IQToolkit.Data.DbEntityProvider.Executor.Execute[T](QueryCommand command, Func`2 fnProjector, MappingEntity entity, Object[] paramValues)
   at IQToolkit.Data.EntitySession.SessionExecutor.Execute[T](QueryCommand command, Func`2 fnProjector, MappingEntity entity, Object[] paramValues)
   at lambda_method(Closure )
   at IQToolkit.Data.EntityProvider.Execute(Expression expression)
   at IQToolkit.Data.EntitySession.SessionProvider.Execute(Expression expression)
   at IQToolkit.Query`1.System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
```

The SQL tab in LinqPad is showing valid SQL

```
SELECT t0.TERM_ID, t1.ZONE_ID
FROM CMN_TERMS t0
INNER JOIN ESI_TERMS_LOCATION_V t1
  ON (t0.ATTRIBUTE01 = t1.TERM_NAME)
```

Answer (score 0):

Wasn't aware, but apparently [the join syntax is not supported in Oracle 8i](http://osdir.com/ml/db.oracle.devel/2003-03/msg00040.html).